# Using custom css in Kendo UI

Tags: jquery, css, kendo-ui, kendo-mvvm

I'm using **Kendo UI** HTML Framework for my web application.

I use Kendo mainly for the out of the box support it offers for MVVM.
However I need the flexibility of Kendo MVVM without having to use the Kendo Widgets. i.e, I want to bind the observable objects offered by Kendo directly to the HTML elements such as div/tables etc.

Example : If I have a datasource object in the kendo.observable view model object **viewModel.dtSource** I can bind to a kendo grid using the code below

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: viewModel.dtSource,
            height: 550,
            columns: [{
                field: "firstname",
                title: "First Name"
            }, {
                field: "address",
                title: "Address"
            }, {
                field: "contact",
                title: "Contact"
            }, {
                field: "gender",
                title: "Gender"
            }],
        });
```

However I want the kendo observable object **viewModel.dtSource** to a HTML table directly instead of using Kendo Grid.

Is this possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. This is possible. Kendo UI is modeled after Knockout JS, though it's not as powerful. You will find an example of how to Kendo MVVM without using kendo widgets here http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/overview

Answer (score 0):

I think using Kendo Grid is awesome if you set it up right! It can be difficult to set up regular HTML to handle data sets that are in the form of dynamic lists. I guess you could make use of [Kendo's Template](//docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/templates/overview) system and set up for loops for that.

The `dtSource.schema` is optional, but it's helpful if you need to organize your data, or interact with it more.

```js
var viewModel = kendo.observable({
    dtSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        schema: {
            model: {
                fields: {
                    firstname: { type: "string" },
                    address: { type: "string" },
                    contact: { type: "string" },
                    gender: { type: "string" }
                }
            }
        }
    })
});
kendo.bind("body", viewModel);
viewModel.dtSource.add({
    firstname: "John",
    address: "123 Main St",
    contact: "555-1212",
    gender: "Male"
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/styles/kendo.blueopal.min.css" />
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.2.607/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="grid"
     data-height="550"
     data-bind="source: dtSource"
     data-sortable="true"
     data-columns="[
         { field: 'firstname', title: 'First Name' },
         { field: 'address', title: 'Address' },
         { field: 'contact', title: 'Contact' },
         { field: 'gender', title: 'Gender' }
     ]"></div>
```